# Function in class can't call outer function

Tags: reactjs

```
function Welcome(props) {
  console.log("Welcome Back");
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleClick(){
    <Welcome />
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>CLICK HERE </button>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

Why function handleClick can't call outer function Welcome? is there any solution to this?

Comment: I think you are getting mixed up between a function and a React Component. If you wanted to call the Welcome function, write `Welcome();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call that function, you should do as follows:

```
function welcome(props) {
  console.log("Welcome Back");
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleClick(){

  }
  
  render(){
    return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>CLICK HERE </button>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

Notice that I've lowercased your `Welcome` function since Pacalcased function names should be reserved for React Components as a general naming convention.

If your intention is to have `Welcome` be a React component, then it should return some JSX and then you should render that out inside of the render function of your class component:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return (<div>Welcome Back!</div>
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleClick(){
    welcome()
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
    <div>
        <Welcome />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>CLICK HERE </button>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

If you'd like to hide your welcome message until you click the button, you can use state:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return (<div>Welcome Back!</div>
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showWelcomeMessage: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleClick(){
    this.setState({showWelcomeMessage: true})
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
    <div>
        {this.state.showWelcomeMessage ? <Welcome /> : null}
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>CLICK HERE </button>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Drf I've updated my answer to include potential scenarios for you.

Answer (score 1):

In your example changing `<Welcome />` to `Welcome()` is enough. But you should use camelCase to define functions. But here is the refactored version.

```
import React from "react";

const welcome = () => {
  console.log("Welcome Back");
};

export default function App() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    welcome();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>CLICK HERE </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the calling of the outer function "Welcome", because it is not a Component:

```
handleClick(){
    Welcome()
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a semicolon after the `Welcome()`.